# How to cancel Task but wait until it finishes?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have threaded task wich performs some operation in loop:

```
static void TaskAction(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (SomeCondition())
    {
        DoSomeSeriousJob();
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}

static void DoSomeSeriousJob()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Serious job started");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Serious job done");
}
```

I start it and then cancel after some period of time:

```
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TaskAction(cts.Token), cts.Token);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    cts.Cancel();
```

This operation must be finished correctly, I don't want to interrupt it. But I want to send a cancellation request to my task **and wait until it finishes** correctly (by which I mean it gets to some point in code).
I tryed following approaches:

#### 1. Wait(CancellationToken ct)

```
try
{
    task.Wait(cts.Token);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Task cancelled");
}
// Must be joined here.
```

In this case program returns immediately from `Wait()`. The task continues to run until `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` but if main thread exits the task gets interrupted too.

#### 2. Wait()

```
try
{
    task.Wait();
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Task cancelled");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Here main thread waits for completion but at the end `AggregateException` is risen with `InnerException` = `TaskCancelledException` (not `OperationCancelledException`).

#### 3. Check IsCancellationRequested() and no exceptions

```
static void TaskAction(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (SomeCondition())
    {
        DoSomeSeriousJob();
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            break;
    }
}
// ...
task.Wait();
```

In this case no exceptions are risen but the task gets status `RanToCompletion` in the end. This is not distiguishable from correct completion when `SomeCodition()` starts to return false.

All these problem have easy workarounds but I wonder, may be I'm missing something? Could anybody advise me better solution?

Comment: If you pass a cancellation token to `Wait` then it will cancel the waiting.  Don't pass the token to `Wait` if you want to wait for the task to finish.

Comment: Re 2, `TaskCanceledException` is derived from `OperationCanceledException`.  If you used `await` instead of `Wait`, then the `AggregateException` would be unwrapped and you could catch the `InnerException`.

Comment: juharr, this is my case 1. What is the use of calling `Wait(ct)` if it won't wait?

Comment: Got it. It waits for completion or raises `OperationCancelledException` if token is cancelled and `Wait()` without parameters waits for completion and raises `AggregateException` if token is cancelled.

Comment: In case 3, if you leave operation after observing that cancellation has been requested, would you still consider the method as finished? To distinguish graceful and cancelled execution, you could use `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to wait for the task to complete (or gets cancelled) synchronously, you can try this:

```
cts.Cancel();
Task.Run(async () => {
    try {
        await task;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex) {
      // ...
    }
).Wait();
```

So that you can directly catch OperationCanceledException instead of catching an AggregateException.

**Edit:**

**Wait(CanecllationToken)**

This approach won't work for that purpose.
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321315%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) statement:

> Waits for the Task to complete execution. The wait terminates if a cancellation token is canceled before the task completes.

**Wait()**

You can use this approach but as you can see, you should expect an AggregateException not OperationCanceledException. It is also specified in [documents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270644%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the method.

> The AggregateException.InnerExceptions collection contains a TaskCanceledException object.

So in this approach, in order to make sure operation is cancelled, you can check if inner expection contains a TaskCanceledException or not.

**Check IsCancellationRequested() and no exceptions**

In this way, this is obvious that no exception is thrown and you can't find out if the operation is cancelled or not.

If you don't want to wait synchronously, everything works as expected:

```
cts.Cancel();
try {
    await task;
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Not as beautiful as I wanted but interesting :)

Comment: Yes, the beautiful way is waiting asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try
{
    task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Task cancelled");
}
```

You'll get an `OperationCanceledException` and it won't be wrapped with `AggregateException`.

Comment: It may work but for unknown reason, [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states that "This method is intended for compiler use rather than for use in application code."

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz, MSDN docs have their share of imperfections and innuendos. This method is widely used and isn't going anywhere as it's a part of the [awaiter infrastructure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx).

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz, as to your approach, `Task.Run` is clearly redundant there. You might as well just do `(new Func<Task>(async () => { ... }))().Wait();`